# Getting MODULE_NOT_FOUND error when using require() for a .js file in sub directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using ExpressJS, when I run my project using 'node server.js' command, I get the following error:

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '../config/db.config.js'
Require stack:

- /Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/db.js
- /Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/models/event.model.js
- /Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/controllers/event.controller.js
- /Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/routes/event.routes.js
- /Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/server.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
  at Object. (/Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/db.js:2:16)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  '/Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/db.js',
  '/Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/models/event.model.js',
  '/Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/controllers/event.controller.js',
  '/Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/routes/event.routes.js',
  '/Users/umairkhan/Documents/nodejs/bohra-calendar/server.js'
  ]
  }

This is my code inside the db.js file:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
var dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

// Create a connection to the database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  user: dbConfig.USER,
  password: dbConfig.PASSWORD,
  database: dbConfig.DB
});

// open the MySQL connection
connection.connect(error => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log("Successfully connected to the database.");
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Here is the directory structure of the project.

[image: Directory Structure of the project]

I have also tried this path: './config/db.config.js' but I still get the same error.

Can someone please help?

Comment: It seems like the db.js is inside the root directory, so `./config/db.config.js` would be the correct path.

Comment: @Christopher Still getting: Error: Cannot find module './config/db.config.js'

Comment: Can there be a space in the file name? Like `' db.config.js'`?

Comment: try absolute path, navigate using the terminal
or try an auto complete path plugin from vscode

Comment: @vsemozhebuty You got a good idea. Indeed, there was a space before db.config.js. Thank you